# Rock Paper Scissors Game - Code does not give me any output

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying make a rock paper scissor game in Python, but when I run and write an input there's absolutely no output on console and no error. Is like when the code runs it got stuck, I'm really not sure why this happen or where is my error. My code is:

```
from random import randrange

computer=randrange(1,4)
human=input("Write your answer (paper, rock or scissor ")

def convertir (numero):
    if numero == "rock":
        return 1
    elif numero == "paper":
        return 2
    elif numero == "scissor":
        return 3
    else:
        return "Write good choice"

result=convertir(human)

while True:
    if result == "rock" or result == "paper" or result == "scissor":
        break
    else:
        continue


def decision (choose):
    if choose == 1 and computer == 2:
        return "You have Lost (YOU: Rock vs COMPUTER: Paper)"
    elif choose == 1 and computer == 3:
        return "You have win (YOU: Rock vs COMPUTER: Scissor)"
    elif choose == 2 and computer == 1:
        return "You have won (YOU: Paper vs COMPUTER: Rock)"
    elif choose == 2 and computer == 3:
        return "You have lost (YOU: Paper vs COMPUTER: Scissor)"
    elif choose == 3 and computer == 1:
        return "You have lost (YOU: Scissor vs COMPUTER: Rock)"
    elif choose == 3 and computer == 2:
        return "You have won (YOU: Scissor vs COMPUTER: Paper)"
    elif choose == computer:
        return "DRAW"
    elif choose == 3 and computer == 1:
        return "You have lost (YOU: Scissor vs COMPUTER: Rock)"
    elif choose == 3 and computer == 2:
        return "You have won (YOU: Scissor vs COMPUTER: Paper)"

convertir(human)
print(decision(result))
```

Comment: The value of `result` is never changed in your `while True` loop, so either it `breaks` immediately or runs forever. You should probably move `human = ...` and `result = ...` within the loop, but make sure not to compare `str` with `int`.

Comment: And since `convertir()` converts the input to a number, the `if` condition will never be true, so it stays in the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask for new input in the `while` loop. Otherwise the loop will keep repeating the same test.

Since you're checking the string format of the input, you need to compare with `human`, not `result`.

There's no need to call `convertir()` again before `print(decision(result))`.

```
from random import randrange

computer=randrange(1,4)

def convertir (numero):
    if numero == "rock":
        return 1
    elif numero == "paper":
        return 2
    elif numero == "scissor":
        return 3
    else:
        return "Write good choice"

while True:
    human=input("Write your answer (paper, rock or scissor ")
    if human in ("rock", "paper", "scissor")
        break
    else:
        print("Write good choice")

result=convertir(human)

def decision (choose):
    if choose == 1 and computer == 2:
        return "You have Lost (YOU: Rock vs COMPUTER: Paper)"
    elif choose == 1 and computer == 3:
        return "You have win (YOU: Rock vs COMPUTER: Scissor)"
    elif choose == 2 and computer == 1:
        return "You have won (YOU: Paper vs COMPUTER: Rock)"
    elif choose == 2 and computer == 3:
        return "You have lost (YOU: Paper vs COMPUTER: Scissor)"
    elif choose == 3 and computer == 1:
        return "You have lost (YOU: Scissor vs COMPUTER: Rock)"
    elif choose == 3 and computer == 2:
        return "You have won (YOU: Scissor vs COMPUTER: Paper)"
    elif choose == computer:
        return "DRAW"
    elif choose == 3 and computer == 1:
        return "You have lost (YOU: Scissor vs COMPUTER: Rock)"
    elif choose == 3 and computer == 2:
        return "You have won (YOU: Scissor vs COMPUTER: Paper)"

print(decision(result))
```

It's not really clear why you bother to use numbers in the first place. You're not doing anything numeric with it, and it doesn't make the code any easier to read. Why use inscrutible numbers like

```
if choose == 3 and computer == 2:
```

rather than

```
if choose == "scissor" and computer == "paper":
```